# List all member list's items given a criteria on Entity Framework with no loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, database-design

I am developing a custom Google Form's like project. These are the entities related to my problem:

```
public class Form
{
    public int Id;
    public string Title;
    public virtual List<Question> Questions;
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id;
    public int? QuestionId; // Self reference pointer for nested questions (alternatives)
    public string Type; // Radio, checkbox, text or image
    public string Description;
    public virtual List<Question> Alternatives;
}
```

Here's my current tables (example):
[image: Forms]
[image: Questions]

From now on, lets just assume everything is correctly mapped/linked (using Fluent API) and that I can successfuly list all the forms and their questions, as follows:

```
public List<Form> ListForms()
{
    return context.Forms
        .Where(w => w.Questions.Any(q => q.QuestionId != null)) // Useless
        .Include(i => i.Questions.Select(q => q.Alternatives))
        .ToList();
}
```

Based on the both images, the above snippet produces a list of 1 `Form`, with 5 `Question`, when it should be 2 if it skipped the child questions (these should be put into the `Alternatives` list), like so: "What is your gender?", "How old are you?", **"Male", "Non-male" and "I am 18yo or older"**.

How can I edit it in order to list all the forms and all the questions, except those NULL TYPE questions, **WITHOUT USING A VANILLA LOOP** (after the ToList() call)?

Comment: First off, I'm wondering why you put answers in a questions table. If you would put them in their own table (where one would expect them) you would not have to ask this question :)

Comment: Hey, @oerkelens! Some answers are also questions (alternatives)

Comment: Can you include an example of such an answer that is also a question? I'm not getting the point with the given examples...

Comment: The question 1 (id) asks what is your gender, with an "male" (3) or "non-male" (4) child questions. If you choose "male" (id 3), there will be a record in the `Answer` table like this: [id = some identity id; id_question = 3; value = true]. If 1000 users also answer "male", there will be 1000 answers for the question of id 3, just like the Google Forms

Comment: Most people I know would consider "Male" an answer, not a question, and they would pout it in a separate table. If you want your answers in a questions table, go ahead, but this won't be the last problem you run into :)

Comment: You might want to try something like `.Include(i => i.Questions.Where(q => q.Type == null))` if you want the questions, or `.Include(i => i.Questions.Where(q => q.Type != null))` for questions.

Comment: Adding a `Where` inside the `Include` causes an exception: Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: Your problem appears to be your mapping or your model - `Form.Questions` is all questions with a matching (what???) - you seem to be missing columns in your example. In any case, the EF model is defining `Questions` differently from what you expect, your query can't help with that.

Comment: Seems you have questions and allowable responses in your table, why not separate them into questions, questionOptions and answers?

Comment: The part where you do this .Where(w => w.Questions.Any(q => q.QuestionId != null)) is quite useless as you pointed out. This is because you are effectivley saying: Get me all forms that have at least one question that has a aparent question. You can completely get rid of that since you are interested in questions. Can you try and put that condition in Include method you call.

Comment: @Rob two others have said that, although it wont work because EF does not support `include filtering` as of now (6.1.3).
@NetMage that sounds good, however what will be the FKs of `Answer`? Will it point to two other tables (`Question` and `QuestionOption`)?